# Question about eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^2 V$ given eigenvalues of V.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, tensor-products

I was reading Lecture 2 in fulton and harris about characters and the authors say that if the representation $V$ has eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$ Then $\bigwedge^2 V$ has eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\lambda_j|i<j\}$.  Why is this true?

Note: $\bigwedge$ is the alternating tensor.

Comment: What is $\bigwedge$?

Comment: I'm not clear on what it means for a vector space to have eigenvalues. Do you mean a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, then the induced map $\bigwedge^2 V\to \bigwedge^2 V$ has eigenvalues ...?

Comment: By $V$, I really mean the representation at $g, \rho(g)$.   I made other edits to clarify what $\bigwedge$ is.  So for $\bigwedge^2V$, I mean the induced representation.

Comment: So, $V$ is a representation of a group $G$ and for a fixed $g\in G$, $\rho(g)$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$? Is that right?

Comment: Hint: If $v_1,v_2\in V$ are eigenvectors for the action with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, what can you say about $v_1\otimes v_2$ (seen as an element in the exterior power)?

Comment: @DavidHill yes, that is correct.  @ Tobias Kiledtoft For tensor products I know $g\cdot (v_1\otimes v_2 = g\cdot v_1\otimes g\cdot v_2 = \lambda_1 v_1\otimes \lambda_2 v_2 = \lambda_1\lambda_2(v_1\otimes v_2)$. but I dont understand what the difference would be for alternating tensors

Comment: Well, how have you defined the exterior power? As a submodule or as a quotient of the tensor square?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft Fulton and harris define it in two ways one is the tensor square quotient out by the subgroup generated by elements with two vectors identical and the other is as a multilinear alternating mapping from $V\times V \to U$

Comment: Where $U$ is what? Anyway, the first is a good one to work with here, as it should be clear what happens to the vectors.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay so you mean to say that because $v_i\otimes v_i=0$, $\lambda_i \lambda_i$ is not an eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30035/discussion-between-bobby-jones-and-tobias-kildetoft).